# Vuetify 2: make a v-text-field update its model only on loss of focus

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm using a `v-text-field` in Vuetify 2.  I want it to update its model *only* when the component loses focus (as opposed to updating the model after every keypress).  I want this because it's a number which is formatted to two decimal places.  I want "12" to become "12.00" after the user navigates away, but not while the user is typing, because the user may type additional digits before the decimal point.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to change the v-model to it's [expanded form](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) that uses both `v-bind:value` and `v-on:input`.  Instead of using the `input` event which fires on every user input, you'll want to use the [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) which fires under the following condition:

> **When the element loses focus after its value was changed**: for elements where the user's interaction is typing rather than selection, such as a `<textarea>` or the `text`, `search`, `url`, `tel`, `email`, or `password` types of the `<input>` element.

Native `<input>` element would give you the element's value on `$event.target.value`, but with Vuetify's `<v-text-field>` the value is just on `$event` so you can set up your v-text-field like this:

```html
<v-text-field
  type="number"
  :value="text"
  @change="text = $event"
></v-text-field>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
     text: ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/zYMrNPp?editors=1011)